# How to pass a module input to a parent app?

Tags: r, shiny

I found this [post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/shiny-module-design-patterns-pass-module-inputs-to-other-modules/) on how to pass input between modules, but I am not sure how to pass a module to a parent app.

If I have a module **ui1.R**

```
ui1UI <-  function(id, label = "ui1UI") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  shinyUI(fluidPage(
    textInput(ns('id'), 'ID'),
    actionButton(ns("confirm"), "Submit", class='btn-primary')

  ))
}

ui1 <- function(input, output, session) {

  cond <- reactive({ input$confirm})

  observeEvent(length(input$id)!="", {
    toggleState("confirm")
  })

  return(cond)

}
```

And I want to access `cond` from **server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  cond <- callModule(ui1, "ui1")
  callModule(server, "ui1a", cond)

  output$page <- renderUI(expr= if(is.null(cond())) {
    ui1UI('ui1')
    } else {
    ui2UI('ui2')
    }

    )
})
```

How to I pass the value of `cond` to `server.R`?

The rest of the app is:

**ui.R**

```
tagList(useShinyjs(), htmlOutput("page"))
```

**global.R**

```
rm(list=ls())
source('ui1.R')
source('ui2.R')
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
```

**ui2.R**

```
ui2UI <-  function(id, label = "ui2UI") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  shinyUI(fluidPage(
    textInput(ns('id'), 'Second Page')

  ))
}

ui2 <- function(input, output, session) {

}
```

Eventually, I would expect **ui1.R** to be rendered, but I get **ui2.R** instead, as if `cond` wasn't received in the `if()`.

ps: The r-bloggers post uses `callModules()`. Is it just an old alternative for `callModule()`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your problem is. You have the right idea. Here is an example using your module that displays the value of the action button (which is a bit of an odd thing to want but whatever):

```
library(shiny)
ui1UI <-  function(id, label = "ui1UI") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  shinyUI(fluidPage(
    textInput(ns('id'), 'ID'),
    actionButton(ns("confirm"), "Submit", class='btn-primary')

  ))
}

ui1 <- function(input, output, session) {

  cond <- reactive({ input$confirm})

  return(cond)

}

ui =fluidPage(
    ui1UI("test"),
    uiOutput("example")
  )

server=shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    value <- callModule(ui1,"test")

    output$example <- renderUI({
      HTML(value())
    })

})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added the rest of the app to clarify what is not working.

Comment: Ok I see, there are a lot of problems with the approach you are taking. Essentially what you want is for the first module to display, and then when they press the button for it to switch to module two.

Comment: So on launch it tries to render the `htmlOutput` so it looks to the function in the server, this then has an if then statement based on `cond()` which is an object from the client that doesn't exist yet so it errors. Your if then in the `renderUI` is essentially a paradox

Comment: How can `cond()` exist if `ui1UI` isn't rendered, but how can `ui1UI` render without `cond()` existing?

Comment: Ok the paradox is clear, I was wondering if I could write something like `if (exists(cond) | is.null(cond))` which seems to work but it doesn't ('cause I gues `cond` in fact always exists but `cond()` not?)

Comment: There may not be an elegant way of doing this. I will think about it and post another answer if something comes to mind.

Comment: I thought running first `output$page <- renderUI(ui1UI('ui1'))` would have created `cond`, and then rerunning ` output$page <- renderUI(expr= if(!is.null(cond)) {...} ` would have rerendered depending on `cond()`. It didn't work.

Comment: This seems to work. If you don't find something more elegant and wanna add to your answer, I'll accept `  output$page <- renderUI({ui1UI('ui1')})
  
  observeEvent(cond(), {
    output$page <- renderUI({ui2UI('ui2')})
  })`